# Differential Operator Basics

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $ω = xdy−ydx +zdz$. Calculate $dω$.

This is how I have proceeded:

$dw = d(xdy - ydx + zdz) = dx\wedge dy - dy \wedge dx + dz \wedge dz = dx \wedge dy + dx \wedge dy = 2dx \wedge dy.$

I know this question is a simple one, I am just not entirely confident in my understanding of how the differential operator works and am struggling to find a good explanation online. If anyone could tell me if I am correct or if not could explain where I have gone wrong I would be very grateful.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: By the way, these are usually called *differential forms*, and the operation $d$ the *exterior derivative*.

Comment: Thank you @lisyarus that is very helpful, it may help me find some useful material online. As you can probably tell I am just a beginner to these sorts of things!

Comment: Your approach and answer is right. However these are not differential operators these are differential forms and by definition n-th diferential form is the (n-1)st exterior power of cotangent bundle. You have a differential map/connection to go from n-th form to n+1 St form. It essentially means that w above is an element of one form. And dw is a two form which is is obtained by using the trivial connection. The reason for the simplification is encoded in the exterior algebra. Differential operators are more general objects.